# Aliasing a file path in Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line

I have some files in a fairly deep file path:

C:\Users\Martin\Source\GitWorkSpaces\GitProjectCommandLine\ which causes me a couple of problems.

1. It takes a while to CD to the location (yes I know I could right click on folder in Explorer and open command prompt), but, more importantly
2. I hate having such a long string before my command prompt caret once I get there.

Is there some way when working in a Command Windows that I could alias the above path so I could type something like:

cd projfiles

and it would take me to that path AND also show the command prompt as C\projfiles\ AND allow me to do a DIR at that prompt and be shown the list of files at the long path.

Hope that makes sense. I basically want to alias the long path and use it as if it were the full path.

Cheers,
Martin

Comment: You could use a junction point, if you have permission to create one.  But did you realize that you can change the prompt to not include the current directory?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Hi Harry, no I did not know there was an option to not include the current directory. I just had a quick look in the properties dialogue for a Command Window and cannot see anything in there. How do you set it?

Comment: With the `prompt` command (`prompt /?` for documentation) or by setting an environment variable named `PROMPT`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks @HarryJohnston